# Exception has occurred. PermissionDeniedException (User denied permissions to access the device's location.)

Tags: flutter, dart

Everythings are normal but it says:

```
Exception has occurred.
PermissionDeniedException (User denied permissions to access the device's location.)
```

And shows this line on debug: `Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(`
Here the permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

This is the full code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'dart:async';

// ignore: constant_identifier_names
const double ZOOM = 1;

class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  static GoogleMapController? _googleMapController;
  Set<Marker> markers = Set();
  // ignore: prefer_final_fields, unused_field
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controllerGoogleMap = Completer(); //BURADAN
  late GoogleMapController newGoogleMapController;

  late Position currentPosition;
  var geoLocator = Geolocator();
  double bottomPaddingOfMap = 0;

  void locatePosition() async {
    //USER SURRENT LOCATION
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    currentPosition = position;

    LatLng latLatPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition =
        // ignore: unnecessary_new
        new CameraPosition(target: latLatPosition, zoom: 14);
    newGoogleMapController
        .animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
  }

  // ignore: unnecessary_const, unused_field
  static const CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = const CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(40.7956, 29.4420),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Location").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          // ignore: avoid_print
          print(snapshot);
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            GeoPoint location = snapshot.data!.docs.first.get("location");
            if (location == null) {
              return const Text("There was no location data");
            }
            markers.clear();

            final latLng = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
            markers.add(
                Marker(
                  markerId: const MarkerId("location"),
                   position: latLng,
                   infoWindow: const InfoWindow(
                     title: 'dede',
                     snippet: 'deedci'
                   ),
                   ));  
            _googleMapController?.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
              CameraPosition(
                target: latLng,
                zoom: ZOOM,
              ),
            ));

            return GoogleMap(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: bottomPaddingOfMap),
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
              markers: markers,
              initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
              zoomControlsEnabled: true,
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _controllerGoogleMap.complete(controller);
                newGoogleMapController = controller;

                locatePosition();
              },
            );
          }
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to use permission handler dependency to let user allow required permissions.

Answer (score 5):

Add location permission

```
LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
```

Here is the full code:-

```
void getLocation() async {
LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
    desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);

}
```

Comment: It worked for me. Even not using the `permission` var, it forces the emulator to request for permission to the user. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

add these line before ((getCurrentPosition)) to make it ask for permission

```
bool serviceEnabled;
LocationPermission permission;

serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
if (!serviceEnabled) {
  return Future.error('Location services are disabled');
}

permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
  permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
  }
}

if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
  return Future.error(
      'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your emulator or phone, Try to reach apps setting and go to the app's details that you are making.
There you should be able to set the permissions of the app in your device.
Finally you have to see in the permission section that your app has the ability to reach to your location but it is denied to.
Simply set the permission to be allowed and all done!